# Jacobi Identity of Commutator of Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I want to proof the Jacobi identity of Lie brackets of vectorfields on smooth manifolds.

Let $ X=\sum \xi^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $, $ Y=\sum \eta^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $ and $ Z=\sum \zeta^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $. We defined $[X,Y]=\sum(X(\eta^i)-Y(\xi^i)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Show that $[[X,Y],Z]+[[Y,Z],X]+[[Z,X],Y]=0$.

---

I tried to find antisymmetric parts*, but i faild. My try was:

$[[X,Y],Z]=[\sum_i (X(\eta^i)-Y(\xi^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$,Z]=

$\sum_j(\sum_i(X(\eta^i)-Y(\xi^i))\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(\zeta^j))-\sum \zeta^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(X(\eta^j)-Y(\xi^i))$

I didn't write the other two doublebrackets because it was just too much chaos.
Should i try to go one layer down (eg. with $X(f)(x)=df_x(X(x))$) or am i on the wrong way?

*(like it's done with the matrix commutator)

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the associator?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Timmathsf The associator quantifies how much associativity fails, just as the commutator quantifies how much commutativity fails. Ultimately, you used associativity to answer your own question.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I will add that to my vocabulary. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, a buddy helped me out. Apperently it is easier to go a slightly different way.

The key in his solution is that $X\equiv 0 \Leftrightarrow X(f)=0\quad\forall f\in C^\infty(M)$.

Note: $[X,Y](f)=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))$

Now : $[[X,Y],Z]=X(Y(Z(f)))-Y(X(Z(f)))-Z(X(Y(f)))-Z(Y(X(f)))$

Notation $Z(Y(X(f)))=:ZYX$

And finaly $[[X,Y],Z]+[[Y,Z],X]+[[Z,X],Y]= XYZ-YXZ+ZYX-ZXY+YZX-XZY+YXZ-XYZ+ZXY-ZYX+XZY-YZX=0$